# JavaScript: Cant work out how to get a roll over to work on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This one is probably really simple, but has been racking my brain to ruins for a few days now.
I have a php script that outputs images, and on each out-putted image, when the user hovers over it an elements shows with info & options. However i can only seem to work out how to get each element by it's id, which doesn't work, only allowing the first outputted image to show it's rollover, also Id's should be unique so this way is useless. I then did it by getting the elements classes in Jquery by then i had the another problem, every time i hovered the image ALL of the hidden elements where shown, so a mouse over on image one was showing the options for images 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.... Grrrr!

So tis is the original Javascript i used:

```
function thumbToggle() {
        var opt = document.getElementById("rem");
        var text = document.getElementsByTagName("thumbrem");
            if(opt.style.display == "block") {
                opt.style.display = "none";
                text.innerHTML = "&dArr;";
            }
            else {
                opt.style.display = "block";
                text.innerHTML = "&uArr;";
        }
    }
```

Pretty simple really, but so is my knowledge of JS. So the Js Didn't work for me, nor did the Jquery. Only idea i have to sort this is to add an ID and then concatenate an incremented number after it, thus making each ID unique, then doing the same thing to the ID's in the HTML, making the Id's match.

Only problem is i have no clue how to do it, i have no clue if that would really work and i think it's time i put my hands up and admit i need some Stack overflow lovage.

Here is the piece of the PHP that out puts the images....

```
// image output

<div style='position:relative; display:inline; width:200px; overflow:hidden;'>
    <div style='position:relative;'>
        <a id="thumbrem" onmouseover='thumbToggle();' class='thumbrem' style='position:relative;' href=\"show-image.php?id=$id\">
            <img class='lifted drop-shadow' src=\"thumb.php?id=$id\">
        </a>

// The element that appears on rollover

<div id='rem' class='rem'>          
     <div style='padding-bottom:5px;'>
      <label style='color:#fff;'>Select:</label>
         <form method=\"POST\" action='myimages.php'>
           <input type='checkbox' name='images[]' value='$id'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
         </form>                    
 </div>

     <div style='color:#fff;'>
      <a href=\"myimages.php?id=$id&act=delete\">Delete</a>
             &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <a class='' href=\"myimages.php?id=$id&act=changetags\">Edit Tags</a>
     </div>

 <div style='color:#fff; padding-bottom:3px;'>Size:{$details[$i]}</div>
 <div style='color:#fff padding-bottom:3px;'>Date:  {$date[$i]}</div>
 <div style='color:#fff'>Views:  {$views[$i]}</div>

    </div>          
</div>
```

Cheers guys and girls for reading, i hope to hear from some of you soon.

Cheers in advance, Jamie

Comment: Please DO NOT show your SERVER-SIDE code for a CLIENT-SIDE problem. Dump the PHP, show your HTML

Comment: What Diodeus says is that you must show us only the generated html code and not the "echo ..." code. That's really hard to read this

Answer (score 0):

Within a javascript event handler, keyword `this` is the html element to which the handler is attached.

So you don't need to have an autoincremented id in your thumbToggle function. Just use this to retrieve the hovered link.

Comment: Cheers for your answer Samuel, Been reading about how to use 'This' and attempting to use it for a good hour now. I think i understand what it does.. But I'm really not to sure how to use it, could you possibly shed some light? Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, I have a similar problem and would like to know more... Can you link to the documentation for `this` since I am so brainboggled that I can't find it?